# sql server express Permissions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have made a Web application with the Data Base, in sql server express
I open the server and built the tables in visual studio (I could not find another way)
When I went Data Base website (in online) is saying that I have no permissions,
Does anyone know how I add permissions through visual studio?

error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'UsersTable', database
>   'master', schema 'dbo'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The SELECT
>   permission was denied on the object 'UsersTable', database 'master',
>   schema 'dbo'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): The SELECT permission was denied on the
>   object 'UsersTable', database 'master', schema 'dbo'.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +3279580
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +791
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4927
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +92
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +102
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +552
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) +3114
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) +554
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method) +98
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior, String method) +307
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader() +132
>   KIP_FP.KIPDB.chackUser(String userN) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\KIP-FP\KIP-FP\KIPDB.cs:31
>   KIP_FP.KIPBL.chackUser(String userN) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\KIP-FP\KIP-FP\KIPBL.cs:37
>   KIP_FP.loginUserPage.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\KIP-FP\KIP-FP\Login.aspx.cs:34
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11750641
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +150    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +6016

Comment: Have you created a new database or just tables within the Master database?

Comment: Not related but you might want to try SQL Management Studio rather that going in via Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have permission to make SELECT on the UsersTable table but Application Pool of your web application does not have it, because it is running under another user account which has no permission.
To add permission you have to run something like this:

```
USE master;  
GRANT SELECT ON OBJECT::dbo.UsersTable TO PoolUser;  
GO
```

But first you should find out which user is on App. Pool.

Comment: how i know  where to find out which user is on App. Pool?

Comment: I presume your web server is IIS so this ms article should help:
https://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities
You need to find out identity of your pool.